# Can anyone help me find critical published responses to this paper?

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, methodology

Research and discovery of counterarguments has quite a lot to do with philosophy as a practice, and I'm hoping to improve on my technique and see what others can do.

In line with this, I have a particular project I'm dealing with and want to know more about a concept that Isaiah Berlin touches on in his famous (and awesome) paper, *Two Concepts of Liberty*. For many people, the take-away from this paper is Berlin's division between positive and negative liberty, and a general thesis promoting political pluralism. Yet within this discussion, Berlin notes and argues that a desire for *recognition* provides a greater impetus for political action than the more commonly and publicly cited desire for freedom.

Can anyone help me locate published works that deal with this concept of *recognition* in politics, specifically in relation to Berlin?

Results are appreciated, but the method is more important.

Comment: presumably you are asking people that have experience with the question but i use scholar.google or books.google for these sorts of things, with some success, i guess. googlefu or whatever

Comment: desire for recognition sounds like another way of saying Thumos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recognition notion is inherently Hegelian in its origin. Mostly googling "Isaiah Berlin Hegel recognition" but filtering the results a little bit, I would recommend reviewing the following if you want to see how the idea has worked out in relation to Berlin himself:

(1) [SEP Entry on Isaiah Berlin](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/berlin/)

(2) [*Isaiah Berlin: Liberty, Pluarlism, and Liberalism*](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=qO3tLxWOGncC&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=isaiah%20berlin%20hegel%20recognition&source=bl&ots=TDQ5keeP-q&sig=74Qwa3jxJUqq0rrRCBBsRFtREBA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g_3tU_j4D9Lh8AWn6YCYCw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=isaiah%20berlin%20hegel%20recognition&f=false) esp. on pages 70-72

(3) *Isaiah Berlin and the Politics of Freedom: ‘Two Concepts of Liberty’ 50 ...* - the chapter on "Social Selves" should be on topic [if it isn't then something is amiss]

The work Axel Honneth also seems to be centrally on a politics of recognition as it relates to Isaiah Berlin. See http://faculty.fordham.edu/jeflynn/Flynn_Review_Honneth.pdf .

---

If you want to understand the basis more generally, I would recommend studying Hegel specifically the much-misunderstood master-slave dialectic and its resoultion.

Answer (score 2):

From ["Two Concepts of Liberty"](https://www.wiso.uni-hamburg.de/fileadmin/wiso_vwl/johannes/Ankuendigungen/Berlin_twoconceptsofliberty.pdf) :-

> My individual self is not something which I can detach from my
>   relationship with others, or from those attributes of myself which
>   consist in their attitude towards me. Consequently, when I demand to
>   be liberated from, let us say, the status of political or social
>   dependence, what I demand is an alteration of the attitude towards me
>   of those whose opinions and behaviour help to determine my own image
>   of myself.
>
> And what is true of the individual is true of groups, social,
>   political, economic, religious, that is, of men conscious of needs and
>   purposes which they have as members of such groups. What oppressed
>   classes or nationalities, as a rule, demand is neither simply
>   unhampered liberty of action for their members, nor, above everything,
>   equality of social or economic opportunity, still less assignment of a
>   place in a frictionless, organic State devised by the rational
>   lawgiver. What they want, as often as not, is simply recognition (of
>   their class or nation, or colour or race) as an independent source of
>   human activity ...

This might be compared with [Social Identity Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_identity_theory) :-

> A social identity is the portion of an individual's self-concept
>   derived from perceived membership in a relevant social group. As
>   originally formulated by Henri Tajfel and John Turner in the 1970s and
>   the 1980s, social identity theory introduced the concept of a social
>   identity as a way in which to explain intergroup behaviour.
>
> Social identity theory is best described as a theory that predicts
>   certain intergroup behaviours on the basis of perceived group status
>   differences, the perceived legitimacy and stability of those status
>   differences, and the perceived ability to move from one group to
>   another. This contrasts with occasions where the term "social identity
>   theory" is used to refer to general theorizing about human social
>   selves. Moreover, and although some researchers have treated it as
>   such, social identity theory was never intended to be a general theory
>   of social categorization. It was awareness of the limited scope of
>   social identity theory that led John Turner and colleagues to develop
>   a cousin theory in the form of self-categorization theory, which built
>   on the insights of social identity theory to produce a more general
>   account of self and group processes.

See also: http://www.age-of-the-sage.org/psychology/social/social_identity_theory.html